# How do I replace a value with a substring of that value?

Tags: json, string, edit, jq, in-place

I have some json that looks like this (very simplified):

```
{"files":[
  {"date":"2018-01-08T11:38:36+00:00"},
  {"date":"2018-01-08T11:38:27+00:00"},
  {"date":"2018-01-07T20:02:12+00:00"},
  {"date":"2018-01-07T18:23:26+00:00"}
]}
```

I want to convert the dates to epoch seconds so I can sort them. But this format doesn't quite match what strptime will accept:

```
$ jq '.files[] | .date |= strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")' files.json 
jq: error (at files.json:6): date "2018-01-08T11:38:36+00:00" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
```

So, if I just strip off the last 5 characters I can use the same format, minus the %z. This works:

```
$ jq '.files[] | .date[0:19]' files.json 
"2018-01-08T11:38:36"
"2018-01-08T11:38:27"
"2018-01-07T20:02:12"
"2018-01-07T18:23:26"
```

So, what am I doing wrong here:

```
$ jq '.files[] | map( .date |= .date[0:19] )' files.json 
jq: error (at files.json:6): Cannot index string with string "date"
```

Thanks to @peak I got it worked out:

```
$ jq -c '.files[] | .date |= .[0:19]' files.json
{"date":"2018-01-08T11:38:36"}
{"date":"2018-01-08T11:38:27"}
{"date":"2018-01-07T20:02:12"}
{"date":"2018-01-07T18:23:26"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> jq '.files[] | map( .date |= .date[0:19] )' files.json

There are at least two problems with the above.

You can either write `.date = .date[0:19]`, or (better): `.date |= .[0:19]`

It's not entirely clear what you want, but if the goal is simply to edit the JSON, then one option would be:

```
.files |= map( .date |= .[0:19] )
```

Comment: That's what I did ... the last example, right after "what am I doing wrong." And I cut-n-pasted yours just in case I missed something, same output.

Comment: I thought you'd figure out the second error once the first one was fixed.

Comment: I'm only asking about one error, the one I'm getting with the '.files[] | map...'. Unless you know of a strptime format string that will work for the format I have in my json file, in which case the second error becomes moot.

Comment: The '.files | map ...' version works from the command line, but the query I'm building has this after other filters, so I think I need to make the .files[] version work. You've given me another avenue to explore though.

Comment: The highlighted version with '|= .date[0:19]' does not work. The two options you provided below that do work. Thank you. If you'll fix the highlighted version I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: The highlighted version is a quotation from your question!

Comment: Woops. *blush* Mea culpa. Thanks.